# Magento 1.9 Change Order Status Uncaught Exception

Tags: php, exception, magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9 and have an external application that takes care of shipping. Once the product is shipped a file is sent back to a listener I have written for Magento. I need to update the Magento Order status to complete and am using the following code which  is based on earlier postings on Stackoverflow

```
$order_num = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);

$order_num->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true)->save();
```

I am running into a problem here with the following

```
Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'The Order State "complete" must not be set manually.
```

From what I can find this is because the order state is protected.

I have spent most of the day looking at possible solutions and can not work out how I can change the order status to complete and not throw the error.

I would appreciate it if anyone could give me a clue how to get this to work for 1.9

Regards

Richard

Answer (score 1):

use this code. it is works for me..

```
$order_num->setData('state', 'complete');
                      $order_num->setStatus('complete');
                      $history = $order_num->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);


                      $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);

                      $order_num->save();
```

Comment: Careful, state is to be used internally by Magento.